# Facebook friends ranking API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Dear Facebook engineer and developers,

I found this script [here](https://github.com/arjun024/facebook-friends-ranking-score) that opens an ordered list of your friends based on the most contacted or viewed. Which is functionally needed by my next facebook app.

My question is: in that github link, It is said that FB engineers are keep on changing the API. Is this API formally supported or it is supposed to be a secret? If this is formally supported, can anyone shows me where to find the API doc?

PS: It would be nice if this API is formally supported by FB, because it can open a wide range of possibilities in which an application could serve their users better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

With v2.0+, it is not possible to get a list of ALL friends anymore. You can only get the friends who authorized the App too.

That script does not seem to use the API though, imho it is scraping the info. And scraping is not allowed on Facebook. It is using the integrated typeahead feature, so it will only work while the User is logged in on Facebook, and i think it only works while Facebook is actually opened. I highly doubt that you can integrate it in your own App, even if it would be allowed.

Edit: I think it is safe to use though, so you can just try the script to check out how it works. I don´t see anything malicious in it, it´s a well known script anyway. You can try putting the following URL in your Browser: `https://www.facebook.com/ajax/typeahead/search/facebar/bootstrap/?viewer=YOUR-ID&__a=1`

Of course you could try logging in with your App and using CURL to request the info - but i don´t think it will work with an App Scoped ID (see changelog about App Scoped IDs).